# Springboot-MongoDb required a bean of type could not be found

Tags: database, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect my Springboot aplication to MongoDb. When i ran my application and i got this error:

```
Description:

Field userRepo in com.universitem.service.Impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.universitem.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.universitem.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.data.mongodb.uri= /includes the uri
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

universitem.app.secret=UniversityToken
universitem.expires.in=120000
refresh.token.expires.in=604800
```

Main file :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.universitem.repository"})
public class UniversitemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UniversitemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Security Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Data
public class SecurityConfig {


    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint handler;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint handler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean 
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/comment/getAllUniversityComment{universityId}")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/university/getAll")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/userType/add")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/universityType/add")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/userType/getAll")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/userAuth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
}
```

User Repository file:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    User findByUserName(String userName);
    User findByUserMail(String userMail);
}
```

User Details Service Implementation file:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userMail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user =userRepo.findByUserMail(userMail);
        return JwtUserDetails.create(user);
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserById(Long userId) {
        User user = userRepo
                .findById(userId).get();
        return JwtUserDetails.create(user);
    }

}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I tried to add scanBasePackages to @SpringBootApplication like below. Actually database has been started but when i tried to sent request i got 404 Not Found error on postman.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.universitem.repository"}, exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Hi!  try to extend your repository from `MongoRepository` instead of `JpaRepository`. In case if you are using only mongo in this project you don't need `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

Comment: @artiomi I forgot to thanks. Thanks it worked!